# Flutter - MobSF - Static Analysis

Tags: static-analysis, flutter-ios

I have created a flutter IOS project(empty with default page),
prepared the IPA,
then submit to MobSF Static analysis.

Without adding anything on it, i get 2 high severity issues.

1.
Binary makes use of insecure API(s)
CWE: CWE-676: Use of Potentially Dangerous Function OWASP Top 10: M7: Client Code Quality
OWASP MASVS: MSTG-CODE-8
binary may contain the following insecure API(s) _printf , _fopen , _memcpy , _sscanf

2.
Binary makes use of malloc function
CWE: CWE-789: Uncontrolled Memory Allocation
OWASP Top 10: M7: Client Code Quality
OWASP MASVS: MSTG-CODE-8
The binary may use _malloc function instead of calloc

So, i am not sure if this is a flutter issue, or MobSF issue, or some misconfiguration on IOS Xcode side?

Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Have you got any solution of this problem?